# DragQueryFiles can't obtain the file path

Tags: mfc, cedit

My code:

```
void CWGAccountFilterDlg::OnDropFiles(HDROP hDropInfo)
{
    // TODO: 在此添加消息处理程序代码和/或调用默认值
    CDialogEx::OnDropFiles(hDropInfo);
    wchar_t lpFilePath[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    int nCount = DragQueryFile(hDropInfo, -1, NULL, 0);
    DragQueryFile(hDropInfo, nCount, lpFilePath, _countof(lpFilePath));
    DragFinish(hDropInfo);
    GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT_FILE)->SetWindowText(lpFilePath);
    m_FilePath.Format(L"%s", lpFilePath);
}
```

The 2nd calling of `DragQueryFile` returns 0 (this situation is correct) and `lpFilePath` (this is not the expect) has no data in it. I'm sure that the `nCount` value is valid, no buffer overflow.

The dialog and the CEdit control all set 'accept files' to true. And there is a class named `CMyEdit` implement from `CEdit`, and processed the `OnDropFiles` function.

Answer (score 3):

From documentation for [DragQueryFileW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-dragqueryfilew):

> Index of the file to query. If the value of this parameter is
>   0xFFFFFFFF, DragQueryFile returns a count of the files dropped. If the
>   value of this parameter is between zero and the total number of files
>   dropped, DragQueryFile copies the file name with the corresponding
>   value to the buffer pointed to by the lpszFile parameter.

In the second call to `DragQueryFile`, the second parameter should be between `0` and `nCount`. Test the value for `nCount` to make sure it is greater than zero, and pass zero if you are only interested in the first file.

This assumes there is only one file being dropped. If there are more files, then add a loop.

```
int nCount = DragQueryFile(hDropInfo, -1, NULL, 0);
if (nCount > 0)
{
    //(add a loop to get multiple files)
    DragQueryFile(hDropInfo, 0, lpFilePath, _countof(lpFilePath));
    GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT_FILE)->SetWindowText(lpFilePath);
    m_FilePath.Format(L"%s", lpFilePath);
}
DragFinish(hDropInfo);
```

Comment: You saved me,Thanks.@Barmak Shemirani